# Assign value from drop down list in to custom field

Tags: dependent-picklist

The code below is running, but there is still a problem... the pick list behaviors is well, but when I saved the record I'm losing the value, so my goal is save the pick list's value in to the custom field Long_Imperial__c, has somebody worked on this?... Can somebody give me a hand???

**Controller**

```
public string select_length {get; set;}
public string var_length {get; set;}    
public string var_width {get; set;}

public List<SelectOption> getListWidth() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption> { new SelectOption('','-- Width --') };
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry gr:Customer_s_Price_List__c.Wide_Imperial__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()) {
        options.add(new SelectOption(gr.getValue(),gr.getLabel()));
    }
    return options;
}

public List<SelectOption> getlength(){

    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        var_width = cpl.Wide_Imperial__c;

        if(var_width == null)
        return null;{
        if(var_Product_Type =='Laminated / + 10'){
            options.add(new SelectOption('9','9'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('18','18'));
        }
        if( var_Product_Type =='Plasma' && (var_width =='1/4' || var_width =='3/8' ) ){
            options.add(new SelectOption('9','9'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('18','18'));
        }
        if( var_Product_Type =='Plasma' && !(var_width =='1/4' || var_width =='3/8' )){
            options.add(new SelectOption('9','9'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('36','36'));
        }
    }
    return options;
}
```

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Imperial System" columns="1" rendered="
{!Customer_s_Price_List__c.System_Of_Measurement__c == 'Imperial System'}">
<apex:inputField value="{!Customer_s_Price_List__c.Wide_Imperial__c}"> 
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="size"/>
</apex:inputField>
<apex:outputPanel id="size">
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel style="margin:16px;">Length (Yards)</apex:outputLabel>
<apex:selectList size="1" style="margin-left:-16px;" value="{!select_length}">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!length}"/>
</apex:selectList>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, for everyone who is stacked with the same problem!!!

I resolved this issue changing:

> apex:selectList size="1" style="margin-left:-16px;" value="{!select_length}"

by this line,

> apex:selectList size="1" style="margin-left:-16px;" value="{!Customer_s_Price_List__c.Long_Imperial__c}"

Now it's working perfect!!!

Answer (score 0):

try adding/merging following code lines into your code.

```
/*****Controller*****/
    Customer_s_Price_List__c obj;

    public myControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.obj = (Customer_s_Price_List__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public pageReference customSave(){
        obj.Long_Imperial__c = select_length;
        insert obj;
        OR
        update obj;
    }

/*****Page*****/
    <apex:inputHidden value="{!Customer_s_Price_List__c.Long_Imperial__c}"/>
```

Hope this may help.